# Не строится мультимаршрут JavaScript API Яндекс Карт

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi, cors, яндекс-карта-api

Я использую JavaScript API Яндекс Карт. В простой программе выводится карта (успешно), а при нажатии на кнопку должен построиться маршрут между указанными точками, но при нажатии на неё на карте он не появляется. Google Chrome при этом выводит сообщение в средствах разработчика "Response was blocked by CORB (Cross-Origin Read Blocking)". Как можно устранить проблему построения маршрута?

```js
let center = [55.750625, 37.626];
let map;
function init() {
    map = new ymaps.Map('map-test', {
        center: center,
        zoom: 7
    });
}
ymaps.ready(init);
btn.addEventListener("click", async function() {
    try {
        var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
            referencePoints: [[55.734876, 37.59308],"Москва, ул. Мясницкая"]
        });
        map.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    }
});
```

```css
.map {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #333;
}

[class*="copyrights-pane"] {
    display: none !important;
}

.button{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    user-select: none;
    line-height: 2;
    font-size: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.element {
    display: inline-block;
    
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

.first {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
.second {
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="element first">
        <div id="map-test" class="map"></div>
        <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=my_api_key&lang=ru_RU">
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="element second">
        <button id = "btn" type="button" class="button">Отправить</button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ответ в Google Chrome:
[image: Ответ в Google Chrome]

1]: [![https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnXGl.png
Ответ в Edge:
full-bd680c0f629f6faf321e27e99d3d26933f240eee.js:1448

```
    GET https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search/v2/?callback=id_someid&format=json&lang=ru_RU&token=29d41800606dc8f379773ab637dee6f7&rspn=0&results=1&origin=jsapi2Search&snippets=businessrating%2F1.x%2Cmasstransit%2F1.x&ask_direct=1&experimental_maxadv=200&text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%2C%20%D1%83%D0%BB.%20%D0%9C%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F&type=geo net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, я перепутал ключи разных сервисов карт Яндекса. После замены на корректный ключ программа заработала.